# Create a list (or array) of images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This could be very simple, but I have been looking for the proper answer for hours.

I am working on a visual task for primates and am using the PsychToolbox in MATLAB. What I am currently trying to do is randomize the photo that the subject has to decide on. There are many code examples for randomly picking images from a directory, but the images I am using have already been imported because they were previously used.

For reference here is the code that I have used to import the images randomly from the directory on my computer:

```
% Get the image files for the experiment
imageFolder = [cd '/ALSAMultiracial/'];
imgList = dir(fullfile(imageFolder, '*.jpg'));
numImages = length(imgList);

numTrials  = numImages;

% Generate a random number between 1 and the number of images
randomNumber = randperm(numImages, 1);

% Get corresponding name of the image 
randomImage = imgList(randomNumber).name;

% Now load the image
theImage = imread([imageFolder randomImage]);

% Make the image into a texture
tex = Screen('MakeTexture', window, theImage);

% Draw the texture
Screen('DrawTexture', window, tex, [], [], 0);
```

In this task, I flip between two images: theImage and theImage2. After I do that, I want to choose a random image to show: theImage or theImage2. What I was thinking is that I could make a list or an array and do something similar to what I did previously, but the problem is that I have unsuccessfully tried to make a list and array of these images to repeat the process, but it has not worked. For reference, all of the images in question are jpg and the same size.

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to flip between two images, why don't you define a random bit, if its 0, choose `theImage`, otherwise choose `theImage2`.

Comment: Let me explain: So in the first phase of the experiment I flash theImage, then I flash theImage2. In the second phase, I want to randomly choose theImage or theImage2 to flash after the first phase. I understand what you're saying though, I could try that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to load up a whole directory of pictures into an array, I'd suggest using a for loop over your imgList to read all of your images into an array.  That way, when you generate your random number, you can just reference an array index.

Something to keep in mind with this.  when imread is called, it's going to return a 3D array (red green blue values)  So when you read in multiple images, you're going to have a 4D array.

You can do something like:

```
    clear pictureData;
    clear imgList;
    for imgList = dir(fullfile(imageFolder, '*.jpg'))
        pictureData(i, :, :, :) = imread([imageFolder imgList]);
    end
```

to read in all of your pictures.  Then when you grab a random number, you can grab the specific jpeg data you want with

```
pictureData(randomNumber,:,:,:)
```

Let me know if this is clear or not, I can try to explain further if you have specific questions, or if I've missed the mark completely.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am just trying to load these two specific images (theImage and theImage2) into an array since I now only want to randomly choose between them. I used your method when choosing theImage and theImage2 from the directory. Is it possible to adapt this method to something like "for imgList = dir(fullfile(imageFolder, 'theImage', 'theImage2'))" or is that not possible?

Comment: If you want the two in an array you could do something like...

pictureData(1, :, :, :) = <file path>
pictureData(2, :, :, :) = <file path>

Comment: If you like the answer please mark it as answered :)